# How to upload photo with q_auto in Cloudinary?

Tags: cloudinary

I'm having trouble in rendering my images because the file size is big, so I would like to adjust the size, to render it faster.

I would like to upload my photo like this.
"https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/q_auto:low/woman.jpg"

I would like also to upload like, https://res....../upload/q_60/woman.jpg.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [incoming transformations](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#incoming_transformations) while setting the quality parameter to your desired value. Doing so will apply the transformations before the resource is actually saved on your account.

Another option would be to set a default image quality via your [account's setting](https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload).